# Qual é a diferença entre "culpável" e "culpado"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Consultando o dicionário, só logrei entender que a primeira palavra é unicamente um adjetivo e a segunda pode ser um substantivo ou um adjetivo também.

Por exemplo, alguém que corta árvores é culpável da destruição do meio ambiente ou culpado? Ou alguém que joga lixo na rua: é culpável ou culpado de contribuir à sujeira da cidade?

Porquê? Como mudaria o significado utilizar a outra palavra?

Comment: poderias nos dar exemplos e que sentido queres que se entenda desses exemplos, por favor?

Comment: @Schilive Com certeza; acrescentei alguns exemplos. Avisa-me se precisas de mais ou se algo ainda não está claro

Comment: fazendo jus à idéia dum comentário, comento: os adjetivos podem atuar como substantivos através de derivação imprópria; se quiseres ver mais disso, recomendo veres https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf5.php, por exemplo. Sincera e particularmente, eu adoro derivação imprópria :) Eu também adoro derivação afixal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa acepção, a principal diferença é que "culpado" é uma afirmação ligeiramente mais direta: "*tem* culpa", "*é responsável*"; enquanto "culpável" significa que "*se pode atribuir* culpa" ou "*merece* culpa".

Assim, nos exemplos dados na pergunta, eu diria que "culpado" seria mais comumente usado, mas ambos são possíveis.
E vale lembrar que essas palavras têm também outros significados. Por exemplo, "culpável" pode significar "repreensível, censurável", e "culpado" pode significar "afetado por sentimento de culpa".

Me parece, no entanto, que tudo isto já está claro nos dicionários (e.g., [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/)).

Answer (score 2):

Olhando no dicionário há diferença entre as duas palavras:

> cul·pá·vel (latim culpabilis, -e) adjectivo de dois géneros
>
> 1. A quem se pode atribuir culpa.
> 2. Que tem carácter de culpa ou delito; censurável; criminoso.

> cul·pa·do adjectivo
>
> 1. Que tem ou cometeu culpa.
> 2. Causador (de mal ou dano).
>
> nome masculino
> 3. Implicado; acusado; criminoso ou tido por criminoso.

Nesse caso, culpável poderia ser um sinónimo de suspeito. Por outro lado, culpado já se tem a certeza.

Fonte: [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/culpado), [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/culpavel)